# Vibration when braking

Tags: honda, brakes, civic

I have a 2013 Honda Civic LX. 
I started to feel a vibration when braking, so I bought new rotors and pads from Honda. After installing the rotors and pads, I put the car in reverse and used the brake I heard some loud metal knocking. Then I drove foreword and then when I used the brakes again, the same noise would happen. Every time I changed the wheel direction and pressed the brake I heard the metal noise. But only once until I change the steering wheel direction. 
Then, a few days after driving like that, my car started to vibrate again, plus a continuous metal clicking noise that started after I changed the rotors and pads.

I inspected the pads, rotors, and shims multiple times, but everything looks perfect. Tight and well lubed, but I cant understand the these 2 problems. Does anyone have an idea what the root cause of the noise and vibration might be?

Comment: I edited this to try and make the question more clear. Please let me know if I changed the meaning in any way so we can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You weren't getting any knocking noises prior to the brake work done?  The clicking and knocking is only when you turn the wheel?  I'm sure you made sure the caliper bolts were in good condition, installed tightly and correctly...  I've heard of people having problems after putting on new pads that were incorrect for their model.  Hopefully you compare them to the old ones.  But what you're describing is starting to sound like the outer (lower) CV joints giving out.  Get under there and inspect the CV joint boots behind the wheels.  Are either torn anywhere and leaking grease?

Answer (score 4):

For the noise, I'd suggest one of your caliper brackets is loose enough it will shift under the torque of the vehicle (making the noise), but not enough when just checking it out. Secondly, I bet your brakes are vibrating again because you didn't bed the new brakes correctly.

Comment: Whats bed the brakes?

Comment: @Paulster2- Caliper-related issues was my first thought, too.  What do you make of the vibrating taking a few days to up again as opposed to immediately?

Comment: @Tcharles- Bedding means 'breaking the pads in'.  Look it up to find the methods involved.  Your problem sounds a bit more complicated than that IMO but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gone through the brakes thoroughly, you might want to check the A-arms.  When the bushings wear, they can cause a clunk like that as well as vibration.